# Visual Studio SSDT Database project will not display schema node on restart

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools

I added a project by importing from a database connection.

Everything is fine until I quit VS and relaunch.

All the files are present in the project directory.

VS only shows the Properties and References nodes under the project node.

I can find no way to display the schema node that was / should be there. Compare/update adds a 2nd copy of everything with _1 on the end of every file.

Is there a fix / way to get these files in the solution explorer again  ?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't save the solution/project after import. I suggest you to delete everything and start from scratch.